# In r, the pmap function is breaking for me

Tags: r, purrr, pmap

```
x <- list(1, 10, 100)
y <- list(1, 2, 3)
z <- list(5, 50, 500)

purrr::pmap(list(x, y, z), sum)
```

output is:

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL
```

Actually, this is an example from the function documentation.

Comment: What is your `sessionInfo()`? In any event restarting R should fix your issue.

Comment: Works for me. Did you overwrite the `sum` function? What if you try `purrr::pmap(list(x, y, z), base::sum)`